# CSS not working when page loads but works when edited using developer tools in chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css, flask, debugging

I am making a web app using flask and for one of my webpages the css properties that I have set are not working when the web page loads but when I open the developer tools and edit the css it shows up.
This is the CSS code

```
.hidden-box{
height:100px !important;
width:100px;
border:2px solid black;
background-color: black;
color:white;
font-style: italic;
}
```

This is the html code:

```
<div class ='hidden-box'>Here
</div>
```

There should be black box with italic text but just the text(unstyled) shows up.But as I change the width from lets say 100px to 10px it shows up as it should.

I have tried clearing the cache and also restarted the flask server but nothing is working.

Answer (score 0):

The style is perfectly working. here is the pic
[image: the pic]

you should look into the style that you gave to the body of HTML.